# Bash script Output to file fails from script but works from bash

Tags: linux, bash, redirect, scripting

I have this script that checks if the dcos auth login works, but the file i am redirecting the output to is always zero size, when i run the script from bash shell the file is greater than zero . what am i doing wrong ?? , the two functions i use below:

```
try_to_login()
{
# first needs to be logged as skyusr
# try to login and log the result to tmp file
# Sometimes the file is empty so we try again to login
# if the second time is OK it jumps to check the output
cd /home/skyusr/scripts/
dcos auth login --username=admin --password=admin > /home/skyusr/scripts/tmp.sal
}

check_login_result()
{
# Checks if the output of the login is "Login Successful!"
# If YES then writes to log file, if not sends mail and writes to log.
#export mail_to="salim.bisharat@amdocs.com,anis.faraj@amdocs.com"
export mail_to="salim.bisharat@amdocs.com"
now=$(date)
text_to_check=$(cat /home/skyusr/scripts/tmp.sal)
if [ -s /home/skyusr/scripts/tmp.sal ]
then
if [ "$text_to_check" = "Login successful!" ]
        then
        echo "$now - Check Successful" >> /home/skyusr/scripts/logs/login_log.log
else
        cat /home/skyusr/scripts/logs/mail_temp.log | mailx -s "!!! CRITITCAL -- Check DCOS login !!!" $mail_to
        echo "$now - !! ERROR ! Sent mail !! " >> /home/skyusr/scripts/logs/login_log.log
        fi
fi
}
```

Comment: Where is the script running from when not run from the bash command line? cron? A webserver? I'm thinking this is just a permissions problem or maybe SELinux.

Comment: The script works as crontab  .

Comment: So maybe you still missed to configure the environment for cron. RobotHumans presented a simple solution to this: https://askubuntu.com/a/117989

Comment: I followed the guide by RobotHumans and it solved my issue, all i did was adding the PATH from the env to the header of the script  and the shell also. , it looked like that:      #!/bin/bash
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/app/Software/jre1.8.0_121/bin:.:.:/home/skyusr:/home/ubuntu/osql
and it solved my issue. it seems that when you cron a script it ignores the enviroment variables, so you need to set it inside the script.

Answer (score 0):

In this script you define, but you do not call the functions. Simply append function calls:

```
    # ...
    echo "$now - !! ERROR ! Sent mail !! " >> /home/skyusr/scripts/logs/login_log.log 
    fi
fi
} # ... the last line of your script here

try_to_login # calls here ...
check_login_result
```

Comment: I do call them, but i put here only the functions that creates the file from the output of the command i run. The problem is that the file produced is always zero bytes, but when i run the script from command shell it runs OK and the file has >0 size.